# End user reporting designer for .NET App

Tags: c#, .net, reporting

I am designing a .NET desktop app for a small clinical lab. They do stuff like blood tests etc...

When they perform a test they need to print a report. Users should be able to define new types of tests in the system and design the report (that is given to the patient) for that test.

So I need a reporting designer with the following capabilities.

1. can be integrated in to a desktop app
2. can be used by non technical users to create reports
3. Take a business object as the data source
4. Report can be saved in a central location so all the users can access it
5. Once the report is created and saved, the system should be able to populate it with the necessary data (a report of a patient).
6. Should be able to define new reports based on a template - as the report header is same for all types of reports (It has patient data etc...).

Can you point me to a component that supports all of the above requirements ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crystal Reports......

Answer (score 2):

I was for some years in a company that developed a custom Report Designer, and we used components from DevExpress.

https://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Snap/

The requirements you presented, I belive you can do with the DevExpress component, but it will take some work, and the features aren't available out-of-the-box.

There are others components but I don't know them in detail, but you can check them

http://www.componentone.com/SuperProducts/ActiveReports/
and
http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting/creating-reports.aspx